# Handling escape key in c# propertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

i'm using a property grid in winform (c#). once the user enters some values in a property and pressing `Esc` key will clear the value. i just want to prevent `Esc` clearing the value(pressing Esc key should do nothing). i tried the `PreviewKeyDown` but didn't get a clue.

any idea?

Comment: What do mean by a 'clue'? It did not fire, it did not work, or you dont know what to do with it?

Comment: it did not fire. and also there is no Handled method in the eventArgument :(

Comment: in wpf the solution is explained here... probably is same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664884/how-is-esc-key-handled-in-wpf-window

Comment: @Antonio, no unfortunately `KeyDown` does not handle `Keys.Escape` in the `PropertyGrid`