# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.WindowInstance' to type 'System.Windows.Window'

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window

I have created a Style for Window in WPF

```
<Style x:Key="JIMSWindow" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
    <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>        
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>                
    <Setter Property="loc:CloseWindow.EscapeClosesWindow" Value="True"></Setter>
</Style>
```

and the `EscapeCloseWindow` class is this.

```
public static class CloseWindow 
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EscapeClosesWindowProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "EscapeClosesWindow",
           typeof(bool),
           typeof(CloseWindow ),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnEscapeClosesWindowChanged)));

        public static bool GetEscapeClosesWindow(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(EscapeClosesWindowProperty);
        }    
        public static void SetEscapeClosesWindow(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(EscapeClosesWindowProperty, value);
        }    
        private static void OnEscapeClosesWindowChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window target = (Window)d;
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.PreviewKeyDown += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(Window_PreviewKeyDown);
            }
        }    
        private static void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Window target = (Window)sender;  
            // If this is the escape key, close the window
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
                target.Close();
        }
    }
```

Now when ever i open my `View` in WPF MVVM i am getting an exception like

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.WindowInstance' to type 'System.Windows.Window'.
   at JIMS.Commands.CloseWindow.OnEscapeClosesWindowChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\323582\Desktop\JIMS\JIMS.Commands\CloseWindow.cs:line 84
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1& exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& newContainerDependents)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.WpfDependencyPropertyImplementation.SetValue(Object target, Object valueToSet)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Metadata.DependencyPropertyReferenceStep.SetValue(Object target, Object valueToSet)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Core.InstanceBuilderOperations.SetValue(Object target, IProperty propertyKey, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.ModifyValue(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode target, IProperty propertyKey, Object value, PropertyModification modification)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.DependencyObjectInstanceBuilderBase`1.ModifyValue(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode target, IProperty propertyKey, Object value, PropertyModification modification)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.ModifyValue(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode target, IProperty propertyKey, Object value, PropertyModification modification)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.WindowInstanceBuilder.ModifyValue(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode target, IProperty propertyKey, Object value, PropertyModification modification)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.UpdateProperty(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, IProperty propertyKey, DocumentNode valueNode)
```

Please can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: How about just to check if sender is Window?

Comment: Checking if it is a Window instance is half the solution.  Since this code will be run by the designer, and the `d` variable will be an instance of `Microsoft.Expression.WpfPlatform.InstanceBuilders.WindowInstance`, the cast will inevitably result in a null value at runtime, so you have to check whether the cast returns null as well.  If it's null, then you can just skip the logic since it's being run in the visual studio designer where you don't want that logic to run anyway.

Comment: I think it worth to add here a link to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419596/how-does-the-wpf-button-iscancel-property-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can  try to change

```
 Window target = (Window)d;
```

to

```
Window target = d as Window
```

in my machine ,it can go well.

Comment: You actually have to add a reference to Microsoft.Expression.WpfPlatform.dll and then test whether your variable `d` is an instance of Microsoft.Expression.WpfPlatform.InstanceBuilders.WindowInstance or System.Windows.Window, because it will be one or the other depending on whether your code is run by the designer or you run it normally.  In reality, you don't want the logic to actually do anything in the designer, so its probably best to just cast via "as Window" and then ignore it if it's null.

Answer (score 1):

The **WPF** **XAML** designer in **Visual Studio** cannot display any user control that is derived from `System.Windows.Window`. As a workaround, it intercepts this situation and substitutes an internal proxy type of its own to act as the live **XAML** root instead. The type is called:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.WindowInstance
```

And it can be found in assembly `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner, Version=15.0.0.0"`, which I found in the following location:

**`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.dll"`**

---

Anyway, my contribution to this sad debacle is as follows:

> →  Both `System.Windows.Window` and the XAML designer's `WindowInstance` proxy class share the same immediate base class in common, namely `System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl`. ←

This means that by lowering the type of `TargetType` specified on your (e.g.) control `Template` as follows, then it will work for either type. Of course you'll lose the specific features of `Window`, but at least this gives you a stable starting point for further workarounds.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="any_key_name" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Border Background="Green">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Related to this, note that it's possible to programatically detect the `WindowInstance` case at runtime without having to actually load or reference the VS2017 class library cited above at all, by just checking the relevant object (i.e., perhaps from `IProvideValueTarget.TargetObject`) using string comparison: `GetType().Name == "WindowInstance"`.

Anyway, the above example is a trivial `ControlTemplate` defined in **XAML** that does indeed work correctly for both `System.Windows.Window` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio...WindowInstance`, and without the pervasive crashing that, so unfortunately often, detracts from the **XAML** designer's main useful benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to [Radical Framework](https://github.com/RadicalFx/) and change the definition of the Dependecy Property:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowIconProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                            "ShowIcon",
                            typeof(bool),
                            typeof(WindowsManager),
                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, new PropertyChangedCallback((d, e) =>
                                {
                                    if (!DesignTimeHelper.GetIsInDesignMode())
                                        RemoveIcon((Window)d);
                                }
                                )));
```