# C#/WPF How to make close application button from a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I am new to the whole C#/WPF thing and was wondering how to make a button that when clicked will close the application.
I have tried numerous suggestions from google searches like:

- [Close Window from ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172462/close-window-from-viewmodel)
- [WPF Close window with MVVM from ViewModel class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584937/wpf-close-window-with-mvvm-from-viewmodel-class/42585311)
- [https://web.csulb.edu/~pnguyen/cecs475/pdf/closingwindowmvvm.pdf](https://web.csulb.edu/%7Epnguyen/cecs475/pdf/closingwindowmvvm.pdf)
- https://medium.com/@franklyndejesusmejia/close-a-window-from-viewmodel-using-wpf-and-mvvm-pattern-277ec7ef1805
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17aabea0-4aca-478f-9205-fcd56080b22a/how-to-close-a-window-by-clicking-the-button-using-mvvm?forum=wpf
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7Qclpe2joo&ab_channel=BrianLagunas

None of which seemed to help me out properly. Below I have provided the code I currently have that I made following a tutorial on ViewModel navigation. If more code is needed let me know.

**Files:**
[File List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duX28.png)

**MainMenuViewModel:**

```
using Creator.Commands;
using Creator.Stores;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Creator.ViewModels
{
    class MainMenuViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand NavigateItemCreateMenuCommand { get; }

        public MainMenuViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            NavigateItemCreateMenuCommand = new NavigateCommand<ItemCreateMenuViewModel>(navigationStore, () => new ItemCreateMenuViewModel(navigationStore));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainMenuView:** Quit button must close the application

```
<UserControl x:Class="Creator.Views.MainMenuView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Creator.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="720" d:DesignWidth="1280">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Main Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="24"/>
                <Button Content="Create Item" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="18" Margin="20,0,20,5" Padding="0,5,0,5" Command="{Binding NavigateItemCreateMenuCommand}"/>
                <Button Content="Quit" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="18" Margin="20,0,20,5" Padding="0,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Creator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**TL;DR:**
I need to make the Quit button on MainMenuViewModel/MainMenuView to close the application.

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you want. Button to close the Application or just a window. You write `MainMenuView` but it's not a `Window`, but a `UserControl`. If application, then just extend your VM with command, where you call `Application.Current.Shutdown();`.

Comment: @Rekshino yes sorry, I meant the app, thought that the Window and App closing is the same. Will update.

Comment: the solution using provided here is way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16182065/3873053

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close Window from ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172462/close-window-from-viewmodel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your ViewModel with `QuitCommand` and do bind it to the `Button`.

```
class MainMenuViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand NavigateItemCreateMenuCommand { get; }
    public ICommand QuitCommand { get; }

    public MainMenuViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
    {
        NavigateItemCreateMenuCommand = new NavigateCommand<ItemCreateMenuViewModel>(navigationStore, () => new ItemCreateMenuViewModel(navigationStore));
        
        QuitCommand = new RelayCommand((par) => { Application.Current.Shutdown(); });
    }
}

<Button Content="Quit" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="18" Margin="20,0,20,5" Padding="0,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Command="{Binding QuitCommand}"/>
```

Find also implementation of `RelayCommand` in [Why RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand)

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Command** to close a running window in the ViewModel.
You can import the currently running `MainWindow` by handing over the parent control `Window` to the **CommandParameter**.

I made a sample for you by using MVVM.
I hope it helps you.
[Github](https://github.com/devncore/community/tree/main/stackoverflow/answers/quit-button-sample)

### Structure

[image]

#### `MainMenuView.xaml`

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Style="{StaticResource MAIN.DOCK}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Style="{StaticResource MAIN.LABEL}"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource BTN.CREATE}"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource BTN.QUIT}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

#### `MainMenuView.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class MainMenuView : UserControl
{
    public MainMenuView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainMenuViewModel();
    }
}
```

#### `MainMenuViewModel`

```cs
public class MainMenuViewModel
{
    public ICommand QuitCommand { get; set; }

    public MainMenuViewModel()
    { 
        QuitCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(QuitApp);
    }

    private void QuitApp(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Window window)
        {
            window.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

#### `MainMenuResource`

The whole resource source is in the Github.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BTN.QUIT">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding QuitCommand}"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Quit"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Century Gothic"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20 0 20 5"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 5 0 5"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is closing the Window, but not shutting down the application, if you have other shells opened in the same time, you get problems.

Comment: `window.Close()` I think this is a good way. By default, when you invoke Close() on a Window object that you want to close, events such as Closing and Closed also work sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

First i'll create an interface

```
public interface IClosable
{
  Action Close { get;set; }
}
```

then you're viewmodel should implement this interface

```
MainWindowViewModel : ICloseable
{
 public Action Close { get;set; }
 //your code 
}
```

then on the window

```
public partial class MainMenuView : Window
{
    public MainMenuView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainMenuViewModel();
           
        if(DataContext is IClosable closable)
        {
           closable.Close += this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also unhook the delegate before closing window.
Now invoking Close Action in viewmodel will close window.